# Getting ClassNotFoundException SdkClientException in maven project

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, maven

I am java/maven newbie and I am running into this weird issue and was hoping someone can shade some lights on it.
I have two maven project. Project A which is a dependency of class B. Project A in its pom.xml declare aws java sdk as its dependency:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.549</version>
        </dependency>
```

Now Project B declare project A as its dependency and also declare  `aws-java-sdk-s3` with the exact same version as `aws-java-sdk` in project A:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-s3</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.549</version>
        </dependency>
```

However In my Intellij Dependency Analyzer I can see project B is using two version of s3 sdk `1.11.43` and `1.11.549`. But Project A is using the correct version `1.11.549`.

If I run project B inside my docker container it is throwing the following error:

```
... 41 more Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
com.amazonaws.SdkClientException    at 
java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)    at 
org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedUR
LClassLoader.java:93)   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ... 53 more
```

However when I remove the s3 sdk from dependency of project B the application come up successfully!

Can someone please explain to me or show me some pointers on how to debug this?

Also here is my intellij Analyzer
[image]

Comment: did you mean `1.11.543` since i don't see any version `1.11.43` for `aws-java-sdk-s3` module.

Comment: @Sachin No I meant the `aws-java-sdk-s3` I believe that the version can be find [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-s3/1.11.43). Also I have updated my my post with the screen shot of my intellij analyzer